# Thread Control Blocks (TLS variant 2?)

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, x86, elf, thread-local-storage

I am currently implementing an emulator to run 32-bit x86 ELF files (compiled with GCC), and I am trying to understand TLS (Thread Local Storage).

Having read Ulrich Dreppers paper on the subject I have the following question:-

As far as I can understand, the memory referenced at %gs:0 contains a TCB (Thread Control Block). However, I cannot find exactly what structure is stored at this address. Searching through my kernals source code, I can find a couple of structs that look promising (tcbhead_t and a couple of others), but I know that on my system (Ubuntu 2.6.32-41-generic) the value stored at offset 0x10 of the structure is a pointer to the __kernal_vsyscall function, and this doesn't seem to match with the structs that I'm seeing.

If anyone could point out what I'm missing, suggest some relevant documentation, or point me to the correct area of the source code I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Rick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Linux, but in general TLS storage is used to allow *each thread* to allocated arbitrary storage that is specific to the thread.

I assume you are really just emulating x86 instructions (after you've elf-loaded), so elf isn't interesting here.

In that case, you need to simulate TLS storage. That is, for each (you have to keep track of this) emulated thread, you need to keep track of a separate values associated with that thread's GS register.  To do this, you'll need to emulate the OS thread-create/stop/inspect/kill calls, and the OS-TLS initialization calls.    The (emulated) thread-create calls will cause specific allocated space inside the emulated VM to be assigned to that emulated thread's GS register.

Once you have that, emulating the GS accesses should be enough, since everything else about TLS is just regular machine instructions that operate inside the process space.

Comment: Thanks Ira. I understand that TLS stores per-thread data. When you say I need to replicxate the OS TLS initialisation I agree. My question is where is this done/with what structures? Thanks

Comment: It is done when a call to create a thread is made; at that point the OS allocated a TCB somewhere in the virtual space of the process, and sets the GS register to point to that place *for that thread*. You have to emulate this, of course.    Dunno about Linux, but under Windows there are TLS-allocation/access/update routines, which modify the content of that TCB in thread-visible/interesting ways; you have to emulate these, too.  But you shouldn't have to do anything anything else.  ...

Comment: ... What the thread chooses to put in TLS slots is its business, and it will have machine code (that you are already emulating) to process that data.  So you shouldn't have to care about the data structures referenced, any more than you emulator cares about other data structures accessed by the machine code you are emulating.  ...

Comment: ... The only exception I can think of, is that you believe there are some system data structures accessible via the TCB (you kind of mention some).  Unless those data structures are documented as user-thread accessible (or users access them anyway), you shouldn't have to emulate them.  If they are documented as user-thread accessible, then the code you are emulating has machine instructions that access them accordingly. At worst, at thread creation, you have to set them up and fill them in with the documented-accessible values.  I'd be surprised if there was anything actually like this.

Comment: Thanks Ira, that does clarify things a little in terms of finding the relvant code. As you say, the machine code does have instructions for handling TLS data. The strange thing though is that the documentation I have read says that the implementation of the TCB is internal to a given kernal. However, if I compile a C program with GCC, the libc startup code (__libc_start_main) takes the AT_SYSINFO auxiliary vector from envp, and stores it at gs:0x10.

Comment: Hence it appears that there is an assumption by the compiler that there is some kind of structure at that address. As it happens, I could just allocate some block of memory and allow the libc code to do whatever it pleases with it. My question was more so that I could fully understand the details of the implementation on my specific system.

Comment: It appears the compiler decides to *put* some structure there. But that's no different than other application code from your point of view.  The less you have to understand, the more likely your emulator will get completed :-}

Comment: Yes perhaps you are right, in which case I suppose that I will need to go back to the docs to figure out how the linker knows which address to point the segment descriptor referenced in %gs to. That is the difference between ordinary application code and code that references the TCB...the way ordinary code is loaded from the ELF file into the process image is well defined. Apparantly the TCB stuff is a bit murkier. The hunt continues! BTW, there is no chance the emulator will ever be completely finished. Thats partly what makes it interesting...Theres always more to understand :)